# Sharing Home Directory Files w/ Versioning

Tags: home-directory, versioning

I'm curious if anyone has a good solution for the following 'needs':

- Keeping my home directory in sync across various disparate networks
- Ideally versioning the differences.

I've up until this point been using bzr with pushing/pulling to maintain the state of things, but it doesn't retain permissions.

Has anyone else done something similar and come up with a good solution?

Update:

I forgot to mention my platforms.  Well, to make things more difficult, I'm essentially cross-platform: Windows (cygwin) and Linux (gentoo) are my two main ones, but I've been known to flirt with Mac OS X as well, so open options would be great.

Comment: Does bzr allow any pre and post script execution, such that you could get the permissions of the files on the "start" end, and alter accordingly when they're transferred on the "finish" end?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if it is exactly what you need, but for simple files and folder sincronization running in any platform i use Dropbox http://www.dropbox.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

You could try [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/): it does file synchronization between unix/windows/osx platforms and by default synchronizes permissions as well (if that's what you mean with "retain"). I use a setup with a combination of unison and subversion for versioning on some of my homedir files.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a Subversion or git server and then import your home directory into there. You get versioning (most common use case for Subversion and git is source code versioning) and sync'ing.

If you don't want to setup your own server there are cloud-based subversion and git services. Search for github for git and CollabNet for subversion.